# tf.keras.Model.predict and call return different result

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

`tf.keras.Model.predict` and call return different result

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
tf.set
ipts = tf.keras.Input([2])
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)(ipts)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(ipts, x)
model.summary()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
y_train = model(tf.ones((2,2)),training=True)
y_test = model(tf.ones((2,2)),training=False)
sess.run(y_train)
sess.run(y_test)
model.predict(np.array([[1.,1.],[1.,1.]]))
```

`sess.run(y_test)` should be the same with `model.predict(np.array([[1.,1.],[1.,1.]]))` , but the fact is that they are different. Why?

Comment: model.predict could not use training=False

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to register the session as your Keras session with `K.set_session(sess)`. Then `sess.run(y_test)` gives the same result as `model.predict(np.array([[1.,1.],[1.,1.]]))`.

Comment: the reason is that you are using randomly initialised model, so when you call sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) you initialise the model variables in the tensorflow session, while if you call predict, keras initialises the values